# Spark : Not able to convert string to data format

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am not able to convert the string format to date format.

```
val df7 = Seq(("01/01/2007 12:00:00 AM"),("01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM"), ("01/01/2008 12:00:00 AM"), ("01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM")).toDF("r1")
df7.show()
df7.select(col("r1"), to_date( substring(col("r1"), 0, 11), "MM/DD/YYYY")  ).show()
```

Notice in output it is only converting string which has year 2006

```
+--------------------+
|                  r1|
+--------------------+
|01/01/2007 12:00:...|
|01/01/2006 12:00:...|
|01/01/2008 12:00:...|
|01/01/2006 12:00:...|
+--------------------+

+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|                  r1|to_date(substring(`r1`, 0, 11), 'MM/DD/YYYY')|
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|01/01/2007 12:00:...|                                         null|
|01/01/2006 12:00:...|                                   2006-01-01|
|01/01/2008 12:00:...|                                         null|
|01/01/2006 12:00:...|                                   2006-01-01|
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this line

```scala
df7.select(col("r1"), to_date( substring(col("r1"), 0, 10), "MM/dd/yyyy")  ).show()
```

to parse the dates.

There are two changes in the code:

- use the length `10` instead of `11` to cut off the additional space
- the format string is case sensitive and uses the format characters of Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to substring, but give the exact timestamp format.

```
val df7 = Seq(("01/01/2007 12:00:00 AM"),("01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM"), ("01/01/2008 12:00:00 AM"), ("01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM")).toDF("r1")
df7.select(col("r1"), to_date($"r1", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")).show(false)

+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
|r1                    |to_date(`r1`, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa')|
+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
|01/01/2007 12:00:00 AM|2007-01-01                             |
|01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM|2006-01-01                             |
|01/01/2008 12:00:00 AM|2008-01-01                             |
|01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM|2006-01-01                             |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
```